# Why is the pronoun « y » used instead of « en » in the following scenario which contains the sentence « Je n'y manquerai pas. »?

Tags: pronoms, constructions

The following entry is stated in [*Le Robert*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/manquer):
[image]

Why is the pronoun  **y** used instead of **en** in this scenario? Shouldn’t the pronoun **en** be replacing “***de vous informer***”? Is the pronoun **y** used here simply because the response **“Je n’y manquerai pas.”** is an idiom?

Thank you for your help guys!

P.S. I am familiar with rules of the pronouns **en** et **y** but I am still a beginner thus could you please keep your explanation simple. Thank you again!

---

[*Larousse has the same entry*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/manquer/49235):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In forms using ***ne pas manquer de*** + infinitive, the pronoun ***y*** is indeed used to refer to "**de** + infinitive". The Robert and Larousse are definitely right. The form ***ne pas manquer à*** + infinitive is referenced in the [Dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M0575) but it is archaic and as far as I know no more used nowadays.

> *Manquer à*. Suivi d’un infinitif. Négliger ou oublier de faire quelque chose. *Il manque souvent à payer ses dettes de jeu. Elle n’a jamais manqué à remplir ses engagements.* Surtout avec le pronom y et à la forme négative, pour assurer qu’une promesse sera tenue. *Il m’avait promis de venir, il n’y a pas manqué. « Transmettez-lui mes amitiés. – Je n’y manquerai pas.* »
> ...
> Ne pas manquer de (suivi d’un infinitif), ne pas oublier, ne pas négliger de faire quelque chose ; prendre soin de. *Je ne manquerai pas de vous tenir au courant.*

***Je n'y manquerai pas*** is an idiom so shouldn't be over-analyzed. Its meaning is "**I won't forget/miss to do it**", "I will surely do it". It is only used at the negative form: *Je manquerai de vous informer* is very dubious.

One reason the pronoun ***en*** is not used in this specific case is that the resulting sentence would clash with the usual meaning of ***je n'en manquerai pas*** which is "**I won't be short of it**" or "**I won't miss any**", applying to ***ne pas manquer de*** + noun.

> *Je ne manquerai pas de chocolat avec tout ce qu'on m'a offert.*

> *(De chocolat,) **je n'en manquerai pas**.* → I won't be short of chocolate.

> *Je ne manquerai pas de cibles avec mon nouvel arc.*

> *(Des cibles,) **je n'en manquerai pas**.* → I will miss none.

There is also the idiom **manquer à** + possessive, especially with *devoirs* in  *je manque à tous mes devoirs* that leads to *j'y manque* while for example *je manque à mon public* leads to *je lui manque*.

Comment: I upvoted. This question needed a simple and clear explanation from a native speaker, and you provided it.

Comment: @fev I just found that *ne pas manquer à + infinitf* actually existed while I thought it was a mistake.

Comment: That it existed, I've always known. But I never thought "y" could ever replace a "de" phrase! I am grateful the question was asked!

Answer (score 0):

Plus généralement, [en effet](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44427/26366), comme l'explique aussi le LBU (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> §908+R6) : le pronom [*y*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/1) représente ici l'infinitif qui peut être déduit du contexte (par exemple dans « [*Transmettez-lui mes amitiés. – Je n'y manquerai pas.*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M0575) », il s'agira vraisemblablement « (de) (lui) *transmettre* (vos amitiés) »). L'emploi de *manquer à faire* pour « ne pas faire » ou « ne pas réussir à faire » est *vieilli* (LBU). De plus « dans la langue courante, au lieu de *ne pas manquer à*, on dit *ne pas manquer de* », la préposition *de* étant cependant plus rare quand le verbe n'est pas négatif (LBU). Par ailleurs on note que « *n'y pas manquer* est tout à fait courant » (LBU), et cette manière de présenter la tournure laisse croire qu'elle est en effet plus figée. Incidemment, en plus de causer la confusion évoquée dans une autre réponse au sujet de la quantité, et du fait que la valeur du prénom puisse être parfois imprécise, le pronom *en* n'a pas vocation à représenter certains compléments introduits par *de*, comme entre autres l'emploi au figuré d'un verbe (LBU §676).

La [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4314) explique aussi au sujet des prépositions employées avec le verbe *manquer* :

> Le verbe *manquer* peut être suivi de la préposition *de* ou de la
> préposition *à* lorsqu’il est suivi d’un verbe à l’infinitif et qu’il
> signifie « négliger de ». Ces deux constructions sont aujourd’hui
> rares et plutôt littéraires. Cependant, le tour négatif *ne pas manquer
> de*, qui se construit uniquement avec la préposition *de*, est plus
> courant.
>
> [...]
> - Ne **manquez** pas **de** transmettre mes salutations à votre père.

---

Donc 1- [pour éviter la confusion](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44427/26366), 2- oui un syntagme introduit par *de* appelle normalement l'emploi du pronom [*en*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3513), 3- oui c'est un usage particulier. *Generalia specialibus non derogant*.

Comment: _Il était sévère et ne manquait pas À les punir_ (QUIGNARD, Tous les matins du monde, II, 1991), oui vieilli mais on le trouve encore. Pour moi c'est inusité. @jlliagre

Comment: Pour info, les @ suivi d'un pseudo n'ont aucun effet si le destinataire n'a pas déjà posté un commentaire à la question ou la réponse où ce @ est utilisé.

Comment: @jlliagre Je pense que quand j'ai fait le commentaire hier je ne pouvais pas en faire encore ailleurs que sous ma réponse. En fait la réponse se voulait davantage un contrepoids à la réponse retirée, d'où le fait quelle passe plus de temps à discuter des prépositions que du pronom ou de l'antécédent. On essaye de gruger autour mais il n'y a pas grand chose à gruger, finalement je me dis que d'éviter la confusion est l'élément central à tout ça. C'est plus l'idée de cohérence donc que celle d'une exception comme telle, ce à quoi je référais indirectement avec la maxime. Bof.

Comment: @jlliagre La réponse se veut une note à la tienne.